# Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/index.ts starting node app in combination with nodemon

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon

First off, I'm new to this but I'm having a hard time trying to setup a project in node.

The project is supposed to run a graphql server as a backend (running in a docker container)

I'm also trying to set this up with hot reload for easier development.

I created a project using the following steps:

- npm init -y
- npm install -D typescript
- npm install ts-node
- npm install nodemon
- npm install @apollo/server graphql
- npx tsc --init

(some additional info: npm 9.8.1, node v20.6.0)

I created a hello world where:

index.ts

```
let message: string = 'Hello, World!';
console.log(message);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.6.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.9.3",
    "graphql": "^16.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

So far so good, when I run 'npm run dev' it works and I get the following:

/app $ npm run dev

```
> app@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon src/index.ts

[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
Hello, World!
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Now the fun starts :-), I'm trying to use graphql in my index.ts file by adding

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';


let message: string = 'Hello, World!';
console.log(message);
```

nodemon picks up the change and reloads but throws an exception:

```
nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
(node:993) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/app/src/index.ts:3
export {};
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:27)
    at Module.m._compile (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at phase4 (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:649:14)
```

No worries, I'll just add "type": "module" to package.json ...

But no luck, now I get the following exception:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/index.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:142:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:115:20)
    at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:388:13)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:270:56)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:65:26)
    at ModuleLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:282:17)
    at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:34)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:221:17) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
```

Can anybody see what the problem could be?

Maybe nodemon and graphql don't play well together? In that case is there another option setting up hot reload?

Thanks!

Comment: Finally I resolved to using tsx, (https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) which works beautifully. Still wondering why nodemon doesn't work though.

Comment: nodemon has no idea what ts is. Make it run the _js_ file and have watch operation that reruns `tsc` when you update a ts file.

Comment: Also if you solve your own problem in less than 2 minutes after posting, good indication that you posted to SO too soon and it's time to delete your post again ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a simple configuration error

Comment: Ok, I decided to still post even after finding another solution because I thought it could be helpful for people with the same problem.
@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, nodemon seems to know what ts is when "type": "module" is omitted from package.json though.

Comment: Post it as an answer please

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by marking the project as ESM code, and using [tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) instead of `nodemon`:

```bash
npm init -y
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node tsx
```

package.json

```json
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsx watch ./src/index.ts"
  },
  ...
}
```

And running `npm start` to run the code and watch for changes.

Comment: note that there is no reason to install tsx globally, just install it locally too (`npm` scripts can always run CLI commands from the node_modules/.bin dir)